# Result of select into array

Tags: java, sql, hive

Hi I have a 2 tables in hive. I want to insert a result of a query on the first table1 into they array string attribute in the second table2.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
id STRING
);

CREATE TABLE t2 (
ids ARRAY<STRING> 
);
```

For example I can do a simple

```
Select id from table1 ...and some code to insert into table2.ids
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you have some code you are working with, or is this theoretical?

Comment: It's not theoretical, I updated the ask with the table. I have 2 tables: t1 with id attribute and table 2 with ids array attribute. 

I want to implement many to many relation between 2 tables using an array_of_foreign_keys on side (table2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind removing the duplicate ids then you can use the `collect_set` function:

```
insert overwrite table table_with_array select collect_set(id) as ids from table_with_id;
```

Or you can use [this](https://github.com/edwardcapriolo/hive-collect) UDF.

Or you can just get Hive-0.13 and use the `collect_list` function which will keep the duplicates.

Just be careful: `collect_...` functions read all data into memory.